# Is adding a sync passphrase to my google account will make loose all my saved passwords?

Tags: google-chrome, synchronization, passphrase

I've read about the sync passphrase functionality to encrypt the synced data so even google can't read them.

But when reading about it in the official google documentation, they say that :

[image]

The second point in the declaration is ambiguous to me. Does it mean that If I use a sync passphrase I will loose all my saved passwords ? or does it mean that can't save passwords any more but I still have access to my saved passwords ?

Can any one explain it clearly please.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a passphrase, then your passwords are only available when you sign in to Chrome and enter the passphrase. That sentence is describing some features that will be unavailable, namely 1) Viewing passwords on the web, and 2) Storing passwords from Android apps outside of Chrome.

If you change your mind and want to remove the passphrase, you have to click "Reset sync" at https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync, then restart sync from Chrome.